# Como puedo llenar una lista de detalle de productos

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de enviar los datos que cargo del formulario de producto hacia una grilla con los detalles del producto para después enviarlo a la base de datos, pero no puedo insertar los datos en la grilla estuve viendo algunos métodos en la web y no me llena los datos ya que la mayoría
de los ejemplos que he visto los datos son tomados para listar desde la base de datos las grillas y yo lo que necesito es cargar los datos de mi formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen los datos los pongo yo donde obtengo datos desde un servidor de SAP los cuales son el nombre, unidad de medida, Stock y precio por Unidad el total se obtiene a través de un calculo con el botón calcular total donde yo ingreso la cantidad, el descuento y la observacion del formulario.
Estos datos los envió después al controlador que hace las consultas para guardar los datos en la base de datos.
Esta es la estructura de la vista para obtener los datos y enviarlos al controlador

```
     <div class="card card-warning">
      <div class="card-header">
       <h3 class="card-title">Producto</h3>
     </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Nombre</label>
                                                                @Html.DropDownList("Nomb", Model.CargaItem(), new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "drpItem" })
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Nombre", Model.NombrePedProducto, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "500", id = "txtNombrePedido", style = "float:right; margin-top: 25px; display:none" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Nombre")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Unidad Medida</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Unidad", Model.UnidadMedida, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtUnidad", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.TextBox("UnidadMedida", Model.UnidadMedida, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "500", id = "txtUMedida", style = "float:right; margin-top: 25px; display:none" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("UnidadMedida")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Stock</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Stock", Model.Stock, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtStock", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Stock")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Precio por Unidad</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Precio", Model.Precio, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtPrecio", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Precio")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Cantidad</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Cantidad", Model.Cantidad, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtCantidad" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Cantidad")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Descuento</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Descuento", Model.Descuento, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtDescuento" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Descuento")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                @Html.TextBox("CodigoSAP", Model.CodigoSAP, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtCodigoItem", ReadOnly = true, style = "float:right; margin-top: 25px; display:none" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("CodigoSAP")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Codigo", Model.Codigo, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtCodigo", ReadOnly = true, style = "float:right; margin-top: 25px; display:none" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Codigo")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Observacion</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Observacion", Model.Observacion, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "500", id = "txtObservacion" })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Observacion")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Total</label>
                                                                @Html.TextBox("Total", Model.Total, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100", id = "txtTotal", ReadOnly = true })
                                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("Total")
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                                <input type="button" value="Calcular Total" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnCalcular" style="margin:auto">
                                                                <input type="button" value="Agregar Producto" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnAgregar" style="margin:auto">
                                                                @*<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-target="#modal_detalle_seccion" data-toggle="modal"
                                                                            data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" onclick="obtenerdetalle();">
                                                                        <span class="fa-glass">Agregar Producto</span>
                                                                    </button>*@

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <table id="tbpedidos" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
                                                                    <thead>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <th>Nombre</th>
                                                                            <th>Unidad Medida</th>
                                                                            <th>Stock</th>
                                                                            <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                                                                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                                                                            <th>Descuento</th>
                                                                            <th>Observacion</th>
                                                                            <th>Total</th>
                                                                            <th>Acciones</th>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </thead>
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>Cintas</td>
                                                                            <td>Unidad</td>
                                                                            <td>6000</td>
                                                                            <td>1500</td>
                                                                            <td>100</td>
                                                                            <td>10%</td>
                                                                            <td>Venta Cinta</td>
                                                                            <td>135.000</td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                @*<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                                                                    <button  class="btn btn-default btnEliminar"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>*@
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Lo que pasa es que estuve probando un script para realizar la inserción de los datos a la grilla pero no me ha funcionado ya que he ido haciendo las pruebas en la consola y obtengo los datos desde el controlador para obtener un json y ir poniendo los datos en la grilla de la tabla

```
<script>
$('#btnAgregar').click(function () {
    $("#tableResult").html('');
    var nombre = $("#drpItem").val();
    var unidad = $("#txtUnidad").val();
    var precio = $("#txtPrecio").val();
    var stock = $("#txtStock").val();
    var cantidad = $("#txtCantidad").val();
    var descuento = $("#txtDescuento").val();
    var observacion = $("#txtObservacion").val();
    var totalPed = $("#txtTotal").val();

    var params = {
        nombrePedido: nombre,
        unidadPedido: unidad,
        precioPedido: precio,
        stockPedido: stock,
        cantidadPedido: cantidad,
        descuentoPedido: descuento,
        observacionPedido: observacion,
        totalPedido: totalPed
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Pedido/Detalle',
        data: params,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.IsSuccess == true) {
                console.log(response);
                var body = '';
                body += '<tbody style="text-align: center">';
                '<tr class="c-table__row">' +
                    '<td class="c-table__cell">' + response.nombrePedido + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</tbody>';

            }
            $("#tableResult").html(body);

        },
    });
})
```

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Detalle(string nombrePedido, string unidadPedido, int 
    precioPedido, double stockPedido,int cantidadPedido, int descuentoPedido, string 
    observacionPedido, double totalPedido)
    {
        PedidoViewModel pedidos = new PedidoViewModel();
        pedidos.NombrePedProducto = nombrePedido;
        pedidos.UnidadMedida = unidadPedido;
        pedidos.Precio = precioPedido;
        pedidos.Stock = stockPedido;
        pedidos.Cantidad = cantidadPedido;
        pedidos.Descuento = descuentoPedido;
        pedidos.Observacion = observacionPedido;
        pedidos.Total = totalPedido;
        return Json(new { nombrePedido }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

He tratado con varios ejemplos que he visto por la web pero no puedo salir de este problema si alguien me pudiera dar una solucion a este problema

Comment: A ver si entiendo: 1) Llenas el formulario, 2) Presionas "Agregar Producto" 3) El formulario se envía al servidor. 4) En el servidor harás algo con esos datos y retornas una respuesta 5) Al responder el servidor se debe agregar los datos del formulario a la grilla. Es eso???

Comment: En teoria si pero lo que quiero es que al dar al boton agregar estos datos del formulario se muestren en la tabla, como se hace en un carrito de compras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como señalaste que tu problema es pasar los datos del formulario a la tabla, me voy a enfocar en eso solamente.

Lo que veo en tu código, es que cada vez que entra una fila nueva sobrescribes la tabla, esto no es necesario.

Tu deberias tener una tabla de esta manera:

```
<table>
  <thead> <-- TUS DATOS DE CABECERA --></thead>
  <tbody id="tableResultContent"></tbody>
</table>
```

Es decir, el id colocas en el tbody no en table
Luego para agregar con jQuery ocupas la función append() que agrega al final o prepend() que agrega al principio. Tu usas la función html() que sobrescribe el contenido.

Tu javascript debería ser algo así:

```
$('#btnAgregar').click(function () {
    var params = {
        nombrePedido: $("#drpItem").val(),
        unidadPedido: $("#txtUnidad").val(),
        precioPedido: $("#txtPrecio").val(),
        stockPedido: ("#txtStock").val(),
        cantidadPedido: $("#txtCantidad").val(),
        descuentoPedido: $("#txtDescuento").val(),
        observacionPedido: $("#txtObservacion").val(),
        totalPedido: $("#txtTotal").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Pedido/Detalle',
        data: params,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.IsSuccess == true) {
                 fila = `<tr class="c-table__row">
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.nombrePedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.unidadPedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.precioPedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.stockPedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.cantidadPedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.descuentoPedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.observacionPedido}</td>
                         <td class="c-table__cell">${params.totalPedido}</td>
                       </tr>`;
$("#tableResultContent").append(fila);

            }
            

        },
    });
})
```

Comment: lo voy a probar y te comento

Comment: Gracias bro hice unas modificaciones y me funciono